# How does dictionary size (hash table size) grow in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

How does dictionary size (hash table size)  grow in Python ?

```
 a = {}
 sys.getsizeof(a)
>240
a.clear()
sys.getsizeof(a)
>72
```

- Once initialization time  dict size become 240.
- Why does the dict size change to 72 instead of 240 after call the dict.clear() method ?

Comment: I can not reproduce, sys.getsizeof(a) gives 64 in my case on both cases

Comment: I also got 64 in both cases.

Comment: same here 64 on bot case

Comment: My stack "Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux"

Comment: You can go to [Cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) to find the source code of the corresponding version. The implementation of dict objects is usually in `Objects/dictobject.c`.